# regex match in vicinity of anchor

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that finds numbers close to an anchor, but only if they are within a certain distance to that anchor.

Consider the following two lines:

```
The company has a revenue of 2.7 Mio.

The company creates growing revenues and employs more than 25 employees.
```

The regular expression `revenue.*?([\d']+[,\.]{0,1}\d*%{0,1}\s*\w*)` (using python) will find both, "2.7 Mio", and "25 employees". How do I make sure that it only finds the first, i.e. can I make sure that the number it should be looking for is only within 10 characters of the anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'\brevenue.{0,10}?\s+(\d+(?:[.,%]\d+)*\s*\w*)', text)
```

See the [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/P8xz54/3)

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  revenue                  'revenue'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{0,10}?                 any character except \n (between 0 and 10
                           times (matching the least amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [.,%]                    any character of: '.', ',', '%'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: just set a maximum number of characters between the anchor and the rest of the regular expression:

```
revenue.{0,10}?([\d']+[,\.]{0,1}\d*%{0,1}\s*\w*)
vs.
revenue.*?([\d']+[,\.]{0,1}\d*%{0,1}\s*\w*)
```

Sorry for bothering everybody...

You can easily check on regex101.com.

Comment: Consider `revenue.{0,10}?\s(\d+(?:[.,%]\d+)*\s*\w*)`